# LaTeXiT issues on new brew install of MacTex

Tags: latexit

Just installed MacTex with brew and then updated MacTex on my son's MacBook.

Opened LaTeXiT and immediately see two errors:

1.

> ghostscript not found or does not work as expected
> The current configuration of LaTeXiT requires ghostscript to work.
> Unless you have installed X11, you should be sure that you use a version of ghostscript that does not require it (usually gs-nox11 instead of gs).
> Find ghostscript...
> What's that?
> Cancel

2. 

> ps2pdf not found or does not work as expected
> The current configuration of LaTeXiT
> requires ps2pdf to work.
> Find ps2pdf...
> What's that?
> Cancel

I then installed XQuartz using homebrew. Still problem remains.

Brew says it's installed.

```
john@MacBook1415 ~ % brew search ghostscript
==> Formulae
ghostscript ✔
```

Looking at the brew implementation from another mac:

```
12:38:46.642 at iMac191 ~ brew info mactex
==> mactex: 2023.0314
https://www.tug.org/mactex/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/m/mactex.rb
==> Name
MacTeX
==> Description
Full TeX Live distribution with GUI applications
==> Artifacts
mactex-20230314.pkg (Pkg)
==> Caveats
You must restart your terminal window for the installation of MacTeX CLI
tools to take effect.

Alternatively, Bash and Zsh users can run the command:

  eval "$(/usr/libexec/path_helper)"

==> Analytics
install: 2,518 (30 days), 7,385 (90 days), 18,382 (365 days)
```

Comment: see also answer by atom here: https://superuser.com/questions/1787105/where-are-gs-x11-and-gs-nox11-on-my-mac

Answer (score 1):

The binaries were installed... I just had to point to correct directory. Maybe because we are on Apple Silicon M1+ and not Intel - the homebrew install paths are different. This should be looked at by the package manager.

Intel: 
`/usr/local/bin` 
Apple Silicon M1+: 
`/opt/homebrew`

Also important to know that we are searching for term "gs" and not "ghostscript"!

Both binaries are found at these paths on Apple Silicon M1+:

```
john@MacBook1415 ghostscript % echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
john@MacBook1415 ghostscript % which gs
/opt/homebrew/bin/gs
john@MacBook1415 ghostscript % which ps2pdf
/opt/homebrew/bin/ps2pdf
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! That should be better an edit or your question, I guess?

Comment: A standard MacTeX install installs `ghostscript`  in `/usr/local/bin` so that path should have worked. Now that you've installed a version with `homebrew` then these paths are correct, however. @Mensch No, this is a good answer to the question.

Comment: @AlanMunn `/usr/local/bin` is the incorrect directory for Apple Silicon M1+  machines. Homebrew on Apple Silicon M1+ installs into `/opt/homebrew`. For each account on my son's MacBook I had to show LaTeXiT where to find the binaries. This is a new first time install of any tex package.

Comment: @John If `ghostscript` is installed by the MacTeX installer (which it is) and not Homebrew, it will be located in `/usr/local/bin`  Only a Homebrew installed `ghostscript` will be in `/opt/homebrew/bin`.  This has nothing to do with which chip the Mac has.

Comment: It's better to install MacTeX from its installer rather than use Homebrew to install it since most applications assume a standard MacTeX installation not a Homebrew one, hence your need to change paths.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I think the homebrew package manager might want to consider adding a "Caveat" or create a .config file pointing to where binaries can be found depending on which location it uses for installs (depends on chip Mac has). Does MacTeX use a configuration file? AFAIK ghostscript was installed by homebrew... that misconception may have led me astray.